# is there a way to get around size miss match for chunk downloader plugin for unreal engine 4?

Tags: plugins

I am using unreal engine 4.26 and when trying to do update on demand by using chunk downloader plugin from unreal engine and a custom plugin called chunk core , I got stuck on where the file is the not the same as the other and the downloader not over writing that file. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the Manifest correctly? If I remember correctly, in the Editor the manifest was never actually updated (you need to remove it and start UE).